# IOError return message with broken encoding

Tags: python, encoding, exception, python-2.6, shutil

Python 2.6
Linux (CentOS)

I using shutil.copyfile() function to copy file. I write an exception message in the log file if file is doesn't exist. So, i get message with wrong symbols, because my file path contains russian characters. For example:
origin file path - "/PNG/401/405/018_/01200Г/osv_1.JPG" ('Г' it is russian symbol)
file path in message - "/PNG/401/405/018_/01200\xd0\x93/osv_1.JPG"
I'm tried to use this code `print(str(error).decode('utf-8'))` but it's doesn't work. But this code
`print(os.listdir(r'/PNG/401/405/018_/')[0].decode('utf-8'))` work pretty well. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`print(str(error).decode('string-escape'))` - works for me

Answer (score 0):

Lets break down your command:

```
print(str(error).decode('utf-8'))
```

first it will do:

```
str(error)
```

turning it into a string lets call this `temp_string`

then it will try to do:

```
temp_string.decode('utf-8)
```

this will fail as a string object, does not have a `.decode()`, so you will get a error message like this:

```
builtins.AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'
```

it will never get to the `print()`

What you should do is:

```
print(error.decode('utf-8'))
```

alternatively, you can use:

```
print(str(error))
```

Comment: it's doesn't work because 'error' variable is object of  'exceptions.IOError'. IOError hasn't attribute 'decode'.

Comment: it's print - "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/localELO_SKV/PNG/401/405/018_/01200\xd0\x93/osv_1.JPG'"

Comment: Please update your question where and how  you use the shutil.copyfile()

Comment: I'm found a solution. Thanks for help.

Comment: Would you care to post an answer? This way others can see how you solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Well the output is perfectly correct. `'Г'` is the unicode character U+0413 (CYRILLIC CAPITAL LETTER GHE) and its UTF-8 encoding is the 2 characters `'\xd0'` and `'\x93'`. You simply have to read the log file with an utf8 enabled text editor (gvim or notepad++ are), or if you have to process it in Python make sure to read it as an utf8 encoded file.

Comment: But if i print error to the linux terminal by `print(str(error))`, i see wrong characters.